# what happens when there are two continuous breaks in a switch statement?

Tags: c, debugging, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char c = 'a';
    while (i < 2){
        i++;
        switch (c) {
        case 'a':
            printf("%c ", c);
            break;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("after loop\n");
}
```

What will be the output of the above code?
Does the second break mean anything?

Comment: What happened when you compiled and ran it ?

Comment: the ide complains about unreachable code

Answer (score 5):

`break` is a *jump statement* in C. It unconditionally transfers control to a different location in the code. Which means that any code between that `break` and the target point of the jump is *unreachable*, unless there's a label that allows one to reach it.

In your case there's no such label. The second `break` is unreachable and has no effect.

Answer (score 4):

There is no use for a second break statement. 
The break statement has the following two usages:

- When the break statement is encountered inside a loop, the loop is immediately terminated and program control resumes at the next statement following the loop.
- It can be used to terminate a case in the switch statement.

In this case it terminates the case statement. So the second break doesn't get called. It is a useless statement.

Comment: What I meant was the second break which is inside the case after the first break doesn't get called.

Comment: the same principle applies anyway

Comment: I believe the break is used for exiting the current loop.

Comment: You would be correct if it wasn't in a switch statement.  It will not exit the loop.

Comment: @Sajin M Prasad: `break` in C language has more than one use. And in this case: no, it is not used for exiting the current loop.

Comment: Right, in this case it is used for exiting the current case right. My bad.

Comment: Sorry, but still not completely accurate. It doesn't just exit the current 'case' because that implies that it would go on to the next 'case' statement, which is precisely what it doesn't do. It will jump out of the 'switch' statement. May just be semantics, but I find it less confusing if you say it like that.

Comment: I now had a long read about the break, continue and switch case statements and am quite sure we are on the same page. It might be that I could not express myself correctly.